# How can I use “select distinct” and have a range for my rows?

Tags: oracle

I wrote this code in PL/SQL developer and was wondering how I could have one row per range of `t.ttt` in the `select distinct` columns.

Here's the SQL:

```
select count (t.aaa), sum (t.bbb)
from xxx t
where t.qqq IN  ('3')
and t.www like 'A'
and t.eee >= TO_DATE('2008/03/20','YYYY/MM/DD')
and t.eee <= TO_DATE('2009/03/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
and t.ttt >= 10 and t.ttt <= 20
```

What I need is:

1. I need the `count(t.aaa)` and `sum (t.bbb)` as my columns for each `t.www` in (A,B,C,D). I mean that there must be 2 columns (count and sum) for `A`, two columns for `B`, etc. Every counter has 2 columns.
2. and for the rows, I need `t.ttt` ranges: [10-20], [21-30], [31-40].

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: this has been cross-posted on StackOverflow -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800286/how-can-i-use-select-distinct-and-have-a-range-for-my-rows

Comment: I'm closing this because you asked the same Q first on Stack Overflow, as bluefeet pointed out.  This is also a borderline basic query syntax question that would be Off Topic for this site regardless of cross posting.

Comment: There is no need for "regardless of cross posting". i had a question. so its my right to ask it from the ppl who can help me. u were new in this someday and i am now. and i wont be new for always. its basic for u and average for me dude.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea you could build upon to match your specific requirements.

To build the different columns, and the `ttt` ranges, build a query of this form:

```
select
  case when www = 'A' then aaa end c1_a
, case when www = 'A' then bbb end c2_a
....
, case when ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 20 then 1
       when ttt >= 21 and ttt <= 30 then 2
       when ttt >= 31 and ttt <= 40 then 3 end slice
from foo
where
    ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 40
and ...
```

The idea is to get the right column value, or `null`, for each `www` in its own column, and a distinct value for each range.

Once you have that, aggregating is straightforward:

```
select
  count(c1_a) cnt_a
, sum(c2_a)   sum_a
...
, slice
from (
  select
      case when www = 'A' then aaa end c1_a
    , case when www = 'A' then bbb end c2_a
    ...
    , case when ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 20 then 1
           when ttt >= 21 and ttt <= 30 then 2
           when ttt >= 31 and ttt <= 40 then 3 end slice
  from foo
  where
      ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 40
  and ...
)
group by slice
order by slice;
```

Example, assuming:

```
create table foo (www char(1), ttt number, aaa number, bbb number);
insert into foo values ('A', 10, 1, 1);
insert into foo values ('A', 25, 1, 2);
insert into foo values ('A', 26, 1, 2);
insert into foo values ('A', 27, 1, 2);
insert into foo values ('A', 33, 1, 3);
commit;
insert into foo values ('B', 10, 1, 3);
insert into foo values ('B', 10, 1, 4);
insert into foo values ('B', 25, null, 2);
insert into foo values ('B', 33, 1, 10);
insert into foo values ('B', 37, 1, 11);
commit;
```

Then:

```
select
  case when www = 'A' then aaa end c1_a
, case when www = 'A' then bbb end c2_a
, case when www = 'B' then aaa end c1_b
, case when www = 'B' then bbb end c2_b
, case when ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 20 then 1
       when ttt >= 21 and ttt <= 30 then 2
       when ttt >= 31 and ttt <= 40 then 3 end slice
from foo
where ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 40;
```

Will yield:

```
      C1_A       C2_A       C1_B       C2_B      SLICE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1                                1
         1          2                                2
         1          2                                2
         1          2                                2
         1          3                                3
                               1          3          1
                               1          4          1
                                          2          2
                               1         10          3
                               1         11          3
```

So the aggregation:

```
select
  count(c1_a) cnt_a
, sum(c2_a)   sum_a
, count(c1_b) cnt_b
, sum(c2_b)   sum_b
, slice
from (
  select
      case when www = 'A' then aaa end c1_a
    , case when www = 'A' then bbb end c2_a
    , case when www = 'B' then aaa end c1_b
    , case when www = 'B' then bbb end c2_b
    , case when ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 20 then 1
           when ttt >= 21 and ttt <= 30 then 2
           when ttt >= 31 and ttt <= 40 then 3 end slice
  from foo
  where ttt >= 10 and ttt <= 40
)
group by slice
order by slice;
```

Gives:

```
     CNT_A      SUM_A      CNT_B      SUM_B      SLICE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2          7          1
         3          6          0          2          2
         1          3          2         21          3
```

Note: if you want the actual number of lines in the count columns, rather than the number of lines with a non-null `aaa`, replace that part of those `case`s with something like:

```
case when www = 'A' then 1 end
```